# "y" or "yes" -- expectations not met

Tags: python

In the following code, `answer()` works as expected and returns true if input is "y" and false when not, but in `answer2()`, it always returns true.

Can someone explain why this is the case?

```
def answer():
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "y":
        return True
    else:
        return False


def answer2():
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "y" or "yes":  # <- notice the extra: or "yes"
        return True
    else:
        return False


if answer() == True:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"


if answer2() == True:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

Answer (score 7):

The expression, `"y" or "yes"` will evaluate to `"y"`. What you want is:

```
if answer in ('y', 'yes'):
    return True
```

Comment: -1 (1) First sentence is true but QUITE IRRELEVANT. The expression to be evaluated is `answer == 'y' or 'yes'` which is equivalent to (`answer == 'y') or 'yes'` so if `answer` is `'y'`, the result is `True`; otherwise the result is `'yes'`. Both of those results are "truthy" (small-t true) as far as Python is concerned. (2) What you want is `return answer in ('y', 'yes')`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a Python expert, but I suspect in answer2 it should be:

```
if answer == "y" or answer == "yes":  # <- notice the extra: or "yes"
```

In other words, I suspect it's currently parsing it as:

```
if (answer == "y") or ("yes")
```

and just converting "yes" into True, effectively... which is why it's always returning True.

Answer (score 4):

You want

```
if answer == "y" or answer == "yes":
```

you have to test it that way.

Or better still, have a list of affirmative responses and test inclusion;

```
affirmatives = ["yes","y","ja","oui"]
if answer in affirmatives:
```

It's all to do with boolean (True/False) operators. Check out the following:

```
>>> "yes" == "yes" or "fnord"
True
>>> "no" == "yes" or "fnord"
'fnord'
```

If the first part is True, you get True - if the first part is False, you get the right-hand side of the 'or'. Now, by having:

```
 answer == "y" or answer == "yes"
```

you can see how if the first == returns False it returns the second == test...

Answer (score 2):

you need to say:

```
if answer == "y" or answer == "yes"
```

how you did it evaluates as:

```
if (answer == "y") or "yes"
```

which will always be true as "yes" is a non-empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
if answer == "y" or "yes":
```

Note that this is different that:

```
if answer == "y" or answer == "yes":
```

Because "yes" is a non-zero value, the first one will always return True.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the issue:

```
answer == 'y' or 'yes'
```

is always going to return True or 'yes' (effectively True since it is not 0 or None),because it's being evaluated as:

```
if (answer == 'y') or 'yes'
```

so you are always going to trigger the 'if' block and return True.